# AJAX/PHP pop up for validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Anyone can help me. Please. I don't how to have a pop up every validation exist.

I used  `alert(data.message);` but validation says undefined.

**here is my PHP code for the function:**

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

$mydata = $_POST["results"];
$inputs = [];
parse_str($mydata, $inputs);
extract($inputs);
$plate_no_full = "$plate_char-$plate_no";
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars where plate_no ='" . $plate_no_full . "'");
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars where chass_no ='" . $chassis_no . "'");
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars where eng_no ='" . $engine_no . "'");
$rows1 =mysql_num_rows($result1);
$rows2 =mysql_num_rows($result2);
$rows3 =mysql_num_rows($result3);

$errors = [];

if (mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
  $errors[] = array(
    'error_code' => 1,
    'message' => 'That plate number was already taken'
  );

}

if (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
  $errors[] = array(
    'error_code' => 2,
    'message' => 'That chassis number was already taken'

  );

}
if (mysql_num_rows($result3) > 0) {
  $errors[] = array(
    'error_code' => 3,
    'message' => 'That engine number was already taken'
  );

}


if(empty($errors)) {


  mysql_query("INSERT INTO cars VALUES ('', '$plate_char-$plate_no', '$engine_no', '$chassis_no', '$car_year', '$car_brand', '$car_model', '$horse_power', '$torque','$transmission $transmission_no', '$drivetrain', '$length/$width/$height', '$seating', '$condition','$air_bag' , '$front_wheel/$rear_wheel' , '$front_susp/$rear_susp' , '$brake_front/$brake_rear' ,  '$eng_type', '$fuel_type' , '$acquisition_cost' , '$marg_cost', '$selling_price' , '')");
  if(isset($_POST["txt1"])){
    for($i=0;$i<=count($_POST["txt1"])-1;$i++){
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO expenses VALUES ('','$plate_char-$plate_no', '". $_POST["txt1"][$i] ."','". $_POST["txt2"][$i] ."', '". $_POST["txt3"][$i] ."')");
    }
  }

  $response = array(
    'message' => 'Successfully Added'
  );

  echo json_encode($response);

} else {
  $response = array(
    'errors' => $errors
  );

  echo json_encode($response);
}
```

here is my ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('#submitme').on('submit', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
                    var mytxt1 = [];
                    var mytxt2 = [];
                    var mytxt3 = [];
                         $(".expense_name").each(function () {
                               mytxt1.push($(this).val());
                          });                            
                          $(".expense_desc").each(function () {
                                   mytxt2.push($(this).val());
                           });            
                           $(".expense_cost").each(function () {
                                 mytxt3.push($(this).val());
                            });            

                           var perfTimes = $(this).serialize();
             $.post("addfunction.php", {results: perfTimes, txt1: mytxt1,  txt2: mytxt2,  txt3: mytxt3 },   function(data) {

                         if(data.errors) {        } 
                            else {
                                   alert(data.message);
                                  window.localtion.href = data.redirect;
                                           }
                                    });
                            });
                    });
```

Comment: and what gives you `console.log(data);`? Expected data or not?

Comment: what do you mean sir by console.log(data);?

Comment: Instead of: `alert(data.message);` write `console.log(data);`. Now if on windows, in your browser, open console by pressing F12. So what you get in console. Is it expected data?

Comment: Or check the Network tab in the Developer Toolbar, and check the response... but read my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the datatype to your post request so jquery can parse the response, then you can handle the errors like you did:

```
$.post("addfunction.php", {results: perfTimes, txt1: mytxt1,  txt2: mytxt2,  txt3: mytxt3 }, function (data) {

    if (data.errors) {
        var alertErrors = "The following errors were found: ";
        $.each(data.errors, function(index, error){
           alertErrors += "\n" + error.message;//Add each error in a new line 
        });
        alert(alertErrors);
    } 
    else {
        alert(data.message);
        window.localtion.href = data.redirect;
    }
}, "json");//<--datatype here
```

Also the data.redirect value is missing in your response:

```
$response = array(
    'message' => 'Successfully Added',
    'redirect' => ''//add here
);

echo json_encode($response);
```

Fixing the redirect you wrote "localtion" wrong:

```
window.location.href = data.redirect;
```

Comment: Sir the successfully added is already done with your code. Thanks sir. But the error validation does not exist. what should I do sir?

Comment: and sir the redirecting in successfully added form does not working sir.

Comment: Ok, I've made some changes to my post regarding your requests.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to parse the returned JSON as well. This is because $.post is just a preconfigured $.ajax call, which does not (I think) specify which dataType is being fetched.
Hence, your Client-side code cannot immediately access the response as an object.

The simplest option is just to parse the response using jQuery:

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Otherwise you could change your code to use the $.ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
  url:url,
  type:"POST",
  data:data,
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(){
  ...
  }
})
```

Good luck!